# How do I wrap each element in the list into an object?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have the following gremlin query where I am querying multiple edges and then their accompanying verticies

```
     outE('childSolution')
                .inV()
                .local(union(
                     identity()
                     .valueMap(true)
                     .project('solution')
                    ,
                     outE('writtenBy')
                    .inV()
                    .valueMap(true)
                    .project('originator')
                    , 
                    outE('childProblem')
                    .inV()
                    .valueMap(true)
                    .project('childProblem')
                ))
                .fold()
                .project('childSolutions')
```

I am getting back

```
    "childSolutions": [
          { "solution" : { properties... }
          },
          {
            "originator": { properties... }
          }
     ]
```

what I'd like is

```
"childSolutions": [
        { "fullSolution : {
          { "solution" : { properties... }
          },
          {
            "originator": { properties... }
          }
         },
        { "fullSolution : {
          { "solution" : { properties... }
          },
          {
            "originator": { properties... }
          }
         }
     ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide a sample graph and the full query you've come up with? The `.local(union())` approach looks a bit complex to me and maybe there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin, it is always best to supply a Gremlin script that can produce a sample graph so that it can be pasted into a Gremlin Console session. That way those who answer can test their results. In this case, I'll just take a swipe at re-writing your traversal, but I think you need to invert how you are using `project()` and you get a much more readable traversal and one that does what you want:

```
out('childSolution').
project('childSolutions').
  by(project('solution','originator','childProblem')
       by(valueMap(true)).
       by(out('writtenBy').valueMap(true)) 
       by(out('childProblem').valueMap(true)))
```

With `project()` you are specifying up front what you want the keys to be and then using `by()` to say what should go in those keys. The output of this traversal doesn't exactly match what you want, but I think I got it right in spirit. If you want it to match exactly, then perhaps it would be best if you provided a sample graph in your question.